# How to get url from page form element is in?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Let assume I've got two pages a.php and b.php with a form-tag in each page. And the action of both of these forms is c.php.

Is it somehow possible to detect in c.php which form (from eigther a or b) called c.php? It's not possible for me to simply use a  I need a better solution as this hiden-input could be edited in the developer tools in any browser and any user with some developer knowledge would be able to change the value... 
The method in the form tags used is post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a session variable?

Comment: Depends on your usage, I would clear the session variable after the data has been used so that if they go back and forth it should always be a clean, new value. Hard to cater for every possibility, easy to be paranoid about possibility too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the a session in A.php and B.php using something like this.

```
$_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and on c.php `$send_page = $_SESSION['last_page'];`

Make sure to start the session on each page with `session_start();`

Comment: I thought of that too but I think this might not work. In case a user opens a.php. Then I set my session-variable to "a". After that the user opens b.php in a second file and then this session variable is "b". If he goes back to a.php in his first browser-tab and fills the form there and submits there and I call the session-variable in c.php this variable will "b". Is that correct

Comment: That's a good point, probably best just to use hidden form values then.

Comment: Unless you encrypted a hidden field and decrypted it but that's completely unnecessary I think haha. As above, it's really hard to cater for all eventualities, the likelihood of this happening does seem rather slim IMO

Comment: might have found a "solution". Maybe I will combine a session-variable with a hidden input field and compare these values in c.php. If they match the user will get a positiv response and c.php will be executed. Otherwise the user will be sent back to the page from the session variable. Thank you!